# The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly. System.Xml.XmlException: An XML comment cannot contain '--'

Tags: c#, xml, build, solution

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

```
Error       The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly. 
System.Xml.XmlException: An XML comment cannot contain '--', and '-' cannot be the last character. Line 261, position 7.
```

while building the solution above error is occurring in the project file.
i have checked the project file but no any comments present at that file.

Comment: Did you check the project folder for XML files (including sub folders)?.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for comment, I found the resolution it was the mistake in web.config file.

Answer (score 2):

Usually occurs when you merge your branch and comments in your `web.config` are messed up. Just make sure that the config file is a valid XML file and you are sorted.

In my case, it added comment character sequence `<!--` without the closing part `-->.`

Comment: I just excluded my web.config and updated the code again - this resolved it. Thanks for the idea.